# Onelogin IDP initiated SSO

Tags: onelogin

we have used onelogin java toolkit for doing SSO. How ever, we used SP initiated SSO. Could you please let me know if Onelogin java toolkit supports IDP initiated SSO.

Thanks a lot.

Kind regards,
Ajay